# Check if autofilter range is completely hidden

Tags: excel, vba

In my Excel sheet I have a filter in `Row 28` for all other rows below. 
Now I want to check if all rows are hidden below `Row 28`. Therefore, I went with the solution from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052817/consistant-way-to-check-if-entire-range-is-hidden):

```
Sub Check_filter_visibility()
If Sheet1.Range("A28:A10000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 2
End If
End Sub
```

All this works fine.

---

Now, instead of the defined range `Sheet1.Range("A28:A10000")` I want to include the entire `AutoFilter` range. 
Therefore I tried to go with this function:

```
Sub Check_filter_visibility()
If AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 2
End If
End Sub
```

However, with this solution I get `runtime error 424`. 
Is there any other way to make the check if all cells in the `AutoFilter` are hidden independent from a defined range?

Comment: You need to save the autofiltered range in a variable `Set rng = Range.Aultofilter(...)` and then check for visibility `If rng.SpecialCelss(...).Count > 1 Then`

Comment: Maybe `If Sheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already described in the comments the solution is:

```
Sub Check_filter_visibility()
If Sheet1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 1
Else
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = 2
End If
End Sub
```